# Instagram get latest images of a location

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Assuming I have the facebook location ID. Let's take the Eiffel Tower for example.. `223779540985538`. I got the instagram location ID from this facebook location ID, which is `292188415`.

I used the following endpoint to get the instagram location images:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/292188415/media/recent?access_token=***
```

but since the last instagram update all queries return this:

```
{"pagination": {}, "meta": {"code": 200}, "data": []}
```

What's wrong? What I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

if you want search media by its location, you must have lat and long data. you can see example here  : https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/

Comment: https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&access_token=MY_TOKEN RETURNS `{"meta": {"code": 200}, "data": []}`

Comment: it because you run it on sandbox mode......... check your sanbox user, or you must add submission to instagram.

Comment: What are the requirments for submission approval?

Comment: you must submit your app video screencast and fill some form